# Define in a namespace a function already defined in a cpp file

Tags: c++, namespaces

My goal is to declare an existing function from `function.cpp` in a namespace, so I can avoid name duplicates. I do not want to define the function inside the namespace, but on a seperate file (in this case `function.cpp`). I created the following example to represent my effort in the case.

I am new to C++ and I am probably doing something wrong in the definitions, and unfortunately I don't seem to find the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Header.h

int adder(int a, int b);
```

```
//Function.cpp

#include "Header.h"

int adder(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b);
}
```

```
//Namespace.h
#include "Header.h"

namespace orange {
    int adder(int a, int b);
}
```

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Namespace.h"
using namespace orange;

int main() {
    std::cout << orange::adder(7, 5) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: You can't "move" definitions (or declarations) to a namespace. The functions (and variables) must be declared and defined inside the namespace to begin with.

Comment: To clarify, you want to declare an *existing* function into a namespace?

Comment: @user1810087 Yes that is precisely what I want to achieve.

Comment: "I do not want to declare the function inside the namespace"

Btw, you already did it with
`
namespace orange {
    int adder(int a, int b);
}
`

Comment: Well,  **It is highly unrecommanded** and thus I'm not going to answer your question, but it is possible to "move" functions into a namespace with some hacky include tricks. **Note: you will run into issues, if you use this technique!** The idea is to `include` the stuff into the namespace and don't use the original headers and implementations. Can't mention enough to not use this but look at [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WziWGQPkOUQfKCaq)....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

> using namespace orange;

You've included `"Namespace.h"`, which contains already `"Header.h"`, so in your Main.cpp file you actually have

```
int adder(int a, int b);

namespace orange {
    int adder(int a, int b);
}
```

This is totally fine, you can have function with the same name in different namespaces, the first one is in the global namespace, and the second one is in the `orange` namespace.

When you say `using namespace orange;` you bring everything from orange namespace you have in that file to the global namespace, and now, you basically have two `int adder(int a, int b);` in the same place.

When you try to call that function, compiler is confused, he can call both, and doesn't know which one you actually want.

To overcome this problem you shouldn't use `using namespace orange;`, but in the actual call specify which function you want to call, if the global one, then just call

```
std::cout << adder(7, 5) << "\n";
```

If function defined in the `orange` namespace, call this way

```
std::cout << orange::adder(7, 5) << "\n";
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for the answer! I get the linking error LNK1120 in my project.exe for unresolved externals. It seems that the "fucntion definition for 'adder' not found" to be the problem.

Comment: You don't have a definition for ```orange::adder``` function, only declaration.

Comment: Is it possible to "link" the definition in ```function.cpp``` with the namespace header?

Comment: You can also define the function in the ```Namespace.h```, not only declare, but then you should have that function as ```static```, otherwise you'll get multiple definition error.